# As an EU citizen, working remotely for an Irish company, can I keep my job if I move to another EU country?

Tags: eu, eu-citizens, spain, italy, ireland

I am a permanent resident in Ireland, holding Italian citizenship.
I'm an employee of an Irish company and currently working remotely.

I'm considering moving to another EU country, like Spain or Italy, but keeping my job.
I started wondering if this would be possible or not, given I'll move to another EU country but still working for an EU company.

I already discussed this with my manager, and the company is open to keep remote working possible from another EU country, at least for a short term (like 6 months), but they don't know what this could mean if done for a long term.

Is it possible? Will I need to pay in taxes in Spain or Italy?

I'd really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I’d consider doing this if the company I work for ‘doesn’t know what this could mean long term’. There are quite a few aspects to consider from both employee and employer perspective eg https://www.lewissilkin.com/en/insights/working-from-home-abroad---considerations-for-irish-employers

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for the article. I was aware of just few of those aspects. I'll make sure a conversation about it happens in the company I'm working for.

Comment: Not just you might have to pay taxes in Spain, but also the company. They would effectively open a branch office in Spain, staffed by you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the setup.
I did work in ESP for external 1. institute 2.company.

#1 regular worker
#2 freelancer with one company 1 year contract.

In both cases €€€ went to Spanish bank account and I paid taxes in Spain. Medical insurance payments were also obligatory, but I guess you want to have med insurance in the place you live anyway.

In your situation if your Irish employer have no clue about the system be it in Spain, Portugal or whatever then in theory you can start as `autonomo' in Spain, calculating first the before taxes and med insurance payments brutto salary then convincing your boss to hire you as a contractor. This sucks if you have more stable contract right now. Plus you may need to hire some local lawyer/gestoría to handle the various petitions needed to go through it.
Look for **REGISTRO OPERADORES INTRACOMUNITARIOS** since your current company is outside of Spain but in EU.